# what will happen if I override a bean definition in java config?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, configuration, overriding

When developing with Spring Data Mongodb, I want to do some customization in my MongoDB configuraion. 
General, I will extends the AbstractMongoConfiguration, and implement the *abstract methods*. currently, the **AbstractMongoConfiguration** class has the following:

```
@Configuration
public abstract AbstractConfiguration extends MongoConfigurationSupport {
    public abstract MongoClient mongoClient();

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
          return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactor(), mappingMongoConverter());

    ....   
}
```

When extending this class, I want to customize the bean **MongoTemplate**, So I want to override the *mongoTemplate* method, does this work?

```
@Configuration
public MongoConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {
    public MongoClient mongoClient(){
        ....
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
          MongoTemplate template = super.mongoTemplate();
          template.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
    }

    ....   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using `@Override` in this case is not directly related to the concept of overriding a Spring Bean. Spring tracks beans by name, and it's possible to replace a bean with another one with the same name--this isn't used very often, but it's sometimes necessary to get around sticky situations. `@Override` is specifically a Java-inheritance bit.

In your case, your setup should work as you expect because when Spring instantiates your bean, it'll call `MongoConfiguration#mongoTemplate()`. If the definitions were in different classes, then they would both be producing beans named `mongoTemplate`, and the last one evaluated would win (there are tricks to controlling this explicitly, either using `@Order` or injecting the other configuration, but it's not ideal).

Note that in this specific case, you might prefer to use Spring Boot auto-configuration, in which case you wouldn't override the Java method. Instead, you could inject the `MongoTemplate` and just call the setter method on it, either by writing an `ApplicationRunner` or listening for `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Had an extremely similar issue recently.

There are 2 scenarios:

#### Case-1: Overriding without a qualifier

```
@Configuration
public MongoConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {
    public MongoClient mongoClient(){
        ....
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
          MongoTemplate template = super.mongoTemplate();
          template.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
    }

    ....   
}
```

In this case, the bean will be registered by using your overridden definition and not your parent definition. Also, **only 1 bean** will be registered.

#### Case-2: Overriding with a qualifier

```
@Configuration
public MongoConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {
    public MongoClient mongoClient(){
        ....
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name="myBean")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
          MongoTemplate template = super.mongoTemplate();
          template.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
    }

    ....   
}
```

In this case, **2 beans**(`mongoTemplate` and `myBean`) will be created. But, for the creation of both the beans, your overridden implementation will be used.