# Overriding @bean method of abstract class to prevent bean injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, overriding, abstract-class

I am overriding an `@bean` annotated method of an abstract class. I am doing this to prevent bean creation from that abstract class.

```
class AbstractClass {

    @Bean
    OperationClass injectBean() {
        //injects its own type of OperationClass
    }
}


class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Bean(name="customOperation")
    OperationClass injectBean() {
        //inject my own bean
    }

}
```

But, this code ends up registering 2 beans in spring context. What should I do to prevent @bean of parent class from getting fired?

Comment: Do you *really* need inheritance?

Comment: Yeah!! I think you got my problem.

Comment: Take a look at `@ConditionalOnBean` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`

Comment: Saw them. How do you suggest, they fix the above problem?

Comment: I think you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245766/what-will-happen-if-i-override-a-bean-definition-in-java-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning null from `@Bean` annotated method does not register the bean.

```
class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Bean(name="customOperation")
    OperationClass injectBean() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

There's no way to prevent bean registration from the abstract class if your child is scanned by spring. On overriding the parent method you can control the bean creation logic.